# My Features test throws error when i mock a service class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a service class that saves a record to my database, i added the service class in my controller constructor which will be resolved automatically by Laravel service container. I called a method that saves the data to database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Property;

use App\Http\Requests\AddPropertyRequest;
use App\Models\Property;
use App\Models\User;

class AddPropertyService
{
    public function addProperty(AddPropertyRequest $request): void
    {
        $subscription = $request->user()->subscription()->where('status', 'active')->first();
        $numberOfProperty = $request->user()->properties()->count();

        if (!$subscription and $numberOfProperty == 5) {
            throw new \Exception('You need an active subscription to add a new property');
        }

        $request->user()->properties()->create([
            'property_id' => $this->generatePropertyId(),
            'property_name' => $request->property_name,
            'location_address' => $request->location_address,
            'location_country' => $request->country,
            'spaces_available' => $request->spaces_available,
            'currency' => $request->currency,
            'description' => $request->description,
        ]);
    }

    public function generatePropertyId(): string
    {
        $propertyId = 'P' . mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        if (Property::where('property_id', $propertyId)->exists()) {
            $this->generatePropertyId();
        }
        return $propertyId;
    }
}
```

then in my controller i did something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Property;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\AddPropertyRequest;
use App\Services\Property\AddPropertyService;
use App\Traits\ReturnResponse;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
    use ReturnResponse;

    public function __construct(protected AddPropertyService $addPropertyService)
    {
    }

    public function addProperty(AddPropertyRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $this->addPropertyService->addProperty($request);
            return $this->success(message: 'Property added successfully', statusCode: 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->error(message: $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and my test is written as follows

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Property;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Services\Property\AddPropertyService;
use Database\Seeders\PropertySeeder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AddPropertyTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    private User $user;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = User::factory()->create();
    }

    public function testUserCanAddProperty(): void
    {
        $this->mock(AddPropertyService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('addProperty')->once();
        });

        $data = [
            'property_name' => 'Test Property',
            'location_address' => 'Test Address',
            'spaces_available' => 10,
            'currency' => '$',
            'country' => 'Test Country',
            'description' => 'Test Description',
        ];

        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)
            ->postJson('api/property/add', $data);
        $response->assertCreated();
        $this->assertDatabaseCount('properties', 1);
    }
}
```

After this when i run the test the first assertion of assertCreated passed but the database count

```
FAILED  Tests\Feature\Property\AddPropertyTest > user can add property                                                       
  Failed asserting that table [properties] matches expected entries count of 1. Entries found: 0.
.

  at tests/Feature/Property/AddPropertyTest.php:43
     39▕ 
     40▕         $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)
     41▕             ->postJson('api/property/add', $data);
     42▕         $response->assertCreated();
  ➜  43▕         $this->assertDatabaseCount('properties', 1);
     44▕     }
     45▕ }
     46▕ 

  Tests:    1 failed, 1 passed (5 assertions)
  Duration: 0.22s
```

does not work, seem as though its not calling the addProperty method

I was expecting to have the records saved to database and the assertDatabaseCount should be true with 1 value.

Comment: You are literally faking the method that does add the entry to the database (no save code is run because it is faked), so your test is right saying you have 0... I am confused about what you are confused about...

Comment: I thought that faking it would kind of run the code in the method and save my data to the database and I can assertDatabaseCount to 1 . But the data will not be persisted since I’m using the RefreshDatabase trait.

Comment: No, faking (mock) will literaly NOT run the method you are faking, so if you want to use a "fake" database, just have a database that is not production (local database?) and use that one (literally a new schema so it does not mess up your current development environment), read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing), it explains a lot

Comment: You’re correct bro, I had to quickly rush to read the mocking documentation again, the method is not actually executed during the test.